# How make a function NestUntilList that accepts multiple arguments?

Tags: procedural-programming

Recently the looping construct [Until](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Until.html?q=Until) was added to Mathematica in 13.1, based on the [ResourceFunction Until created by Jon Mcloone](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Until).
I want to make a generalization named NestUntilList.
NestUntilList is to NestWhileList as Until is to [While](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html).

This is what I have so far for the definition. The first definition NestUntilList[f,expr, test] works, but the other ones I have not been able to figure out.

```wl
NestUntilList // ClearAll

NestUntilList[f_, expr_, test_] := 
 Join[{expr}, NestWhileList[f, f[expr], test[#] === False &]]
```

I have tried to make them work based on examples for [NestWhileList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html), but what happens is I have to use Task Manager to kill Mathematica because it won't stop evaluating.
I am now working on this.

```wl
NestUntilList[f_, expr_, test_, m_] := 
 Join[{expr}, NestWhileList[f, f[expr], test[#] === False &, m]]
```

Notice with an Until loop we apply the test, then start iterating. That's why I have `f[expr]` as the second argument, not `expr`.
The documentation for Until states, "However, the test is evaluated one more time in the While loop:".
This is based on NestWhileList, which states, "NestWhileList[f,expr,test,m] supplies the most recent m results as arguments for test at each step."

There is an example of

```wl
NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, (Print[{##}]; UnsameQ[##]) &, 4]
```

that I am working on but

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, (Print[{##}]; ! UnsameQ[##]) &, 1]
```

does not terminate. Notice I negated `UnsameQ[##]&` to become `!UnsameQ[##]&`. We iterate until !UnsameQ is True with Until, whereas with a While loop we iterate while UnsameQ is True. How can I make this work?

NestUntilList is sometimes more natural to use than NestWhileList, for example, compare the following ways of computing the next twin prime after 888 with NestWhileList and NestUntilList:

```wl
NestWhileList[# + 1 &, 888, ! PrimeQ[#1] || ! PrimeQ[#3] &, 3]
```

I think it's more natural to do this with NestUntilList.

```wl
NestUntilList[# + 1 &, 888, PrimeQ[#1] && PrimeQ[#3] &, 3]
```

I would like to design a version of NestUntilList that supports cases like this `NestUntilList[f,expr,test,m]`. There are other more general cases like `NestUntilList[f,expr,test,m,max]`, which would apply f at most max times that I would like to solve as well, but for now I want to solve the case of `NestUntilList[f,expr,test,m]`.

Comment: Aargh! Shades of Pascal. -- Why not something like  `NestWhileList[f, expr, Not@*test, {m+1, m}]`? Or `NestWhileList[f, expr, Not@*test, {m+1, m}, max]`. And so forth.

Comment: I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to simply use the negation of the test.

```wl
NestUntilList//ClearAll
NestUntilList[f_,expr_,test_,Optional[m_,1],Optional[max_,Infinity],Optional[n_,0]]:=NestWhileList[f,expr, test[##]===False&, m,max,n]
```

I think this works with all cases. I have not tested it with every possible argument, but here are some examples comparing NestWhileList and NestUntilList.
I am applying double negation with ! applied twice as !!, which represents Not for NestWhileList, and then triple negation with !!! for NestUntilList, which simplifies to !.

```wl
NestWhileList[#/2 &, 123456, !!EvenQ[#]&]
```

and

```wl
NestUntilList[#/2 &, 123456, !!!EvenQ[#]&]
```

both return

```wl
{123456,61728,30864,15432,7716,3858,1929}
```

In this case, I think it might be more natural to use NestWhileList. It also might be more natural to say "Divide 123456 by 2 until you get an odd number."
The next case is to take the log of 100 until you get a negative number.

```wl
NestWhileList[Log[#] &, 100, !!#>0&]
```

and

```wl
NestUntilList[Log[#] &, 100, !!!#>0&]
```

return

```wl
{100,Log[100],Log[Log[100]],Log[Log[Log[100]]],Log[Log[Log[Log[100]]]]}
```

Here we could have computed

```wl
Reduce[!!!#>0]
```

which returns

```wl
#1<=0
```

Find the twin prime after 888. This can be computed with the test PrimeQ[#1]&&PrimeQ[#3]&.

```wl
NestUntilList[#+1&,888,PrimeQ[#1]&&PrimeQ[#3]&,3]
```

The answer is 1019 and 1021.

In this case, I think it's simpler to use NestUntil.

```wl
NestUntil//ClearAll
NestUntil[f_,expr_,test_,Optional[m_,1],Optional[max_,Infinity],Optional[n_,0]]:=NestWhile[f,expr, test[##]===False&, m,max,n]
```

We can just do

```wl
NestUntil[#+1&,888,(PrimeQ[#1]&&PrimeQ[#3])&,3]
```

and get 1021.
The negation is more complicated here with NestWhile or NestWhileList, in which case you could do something like

```wl
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 888, ! PrimeQ[#1] || ! PrimeQ[#3] &, 3]
```

or use parentheses:

```wl
NestWhile[#+1&,888,!(PrimeQ[#1]&&PrimeQ[#3])&,3]
```

Here is an example of using the fourth argument. The documentation states,

> Start comparisons after 4 iterations, and compare using the 4 last values:

```wl
NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, ( !!UnsameQ[Sequence@@Echo[{##}]]) &, 4]
```

We get three echoes of

```wl
{10,5,2,1}
{5,2,1,0}
{2,1,0,0}
```

an output of

```wl
{10,5,2,1,0,0}
```

The documentation example uses Print. I think it's better practice to use Echo, EchoTiming, EchoLabel, EchoFunction, EchoEvaluation, and QuietEcho than Print.

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, ( !!!UnsameQ[Sequence@@Echo[{##}]])&, 4]
```

produces the same results.
Next, the documentation states,

> Start comparisons after 4 iterations, and compare using the 6 last
> values:
> Blockquote
> Here are the two ways that work:

```wl
NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 10,  ( !!UnsameQ[Sequence@@Echo[{##}]]) &, {4, 6}]
```

or

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 10,   ( !!!UnsameQ[Sequence@@Echo[{##}]]) &, {4, 6}]
```

I think the fact that can use a While loop or an Until loop is like how you can either use iteration or recursion for a problem, but often one approach will be a better idea.
Then we have

> Always compare all values generated:

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, (Print[{##}];! !!UnsameQ[##]) &, All]
```

produces the same output as

```wl
NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 10, (Print[{##}]; !!UnsameQ[##]) &, All]
```

(Here is an example of how Print is used in the documentation)
I have a few more things I would like to mention. I thought that SameQ was the same as !UnsameQ, but it's not.
If you want to replicate this

```wl
NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20,!! UnsameQ[#]&, 2, 4]
```

do this

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 20,!!! UnsameQ[#]&, 2, 4]
```

but not this

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 20,SameQ[#]&, 2, 4]
```

Here's a few more examples with more arguments:

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, #1<=1&, 1, \[Infinity]]
```

returns

```wl
{20,10,5,2,1}
```

Then

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, #1<=1&, 1, \[Infinity],1]
```

iterates 1 more time to give

```wl
{20,10,5,2,1,0}
```

On the other hand to iterate 1 times less, do

```wl
NestUntilList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, #1<=1&, 1, \[Infinity],-1]
```

to get

```wl
{20,10,5,2}
```

Here's an example where we do a modular operation until we get 1 that I think is more natural with NestUntilList

```wl
NestUntilList[Mod[2 #, 19] &, 2, # ===1 &]
```

If we apply Length to this list, we get the same result as

```wl
MultiplicativeOrder[2, 19]
```

This next case is tricky, like SameQ and UnsameQ.
Say you want to go from

```wl
NestWhileList[Mod[5 #, 7] &, 4, Unequal[##]&, All]
```

to NestUntilList.
Doing

```wl
NestUntilList[Mod[5 #, 7] &, 4, Equal[##]&, All]
```

will *not* work. It will just output {4}, which is not the same as the output of `{4,6,2,3,1,5,4}`.
Use !

```wl
 NestUntilList[Mod[5 #, 7] &, 4, !Unequal[##]&, All]
```

The documentation for [Unequal](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) states

> The negation of three-argument Unequal is not equivalent to
> three-argument Equal:
> Last but not least, I have another example where NestUntilList is more natural. Say you want to iterate until your margin of error is less than 0.001. You can do

```wl
NestUntilList[(# + 2/# )/2 &, 1, Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.001 &, 2]
```

which I think is clearer to understand, or

```wl
NestWhileList[(# + 2/# )/2 &, 1, Abs[#1 - #2] > 0.001 &, 2]
```

The documentation states for this

> Apply Newton iterations for  until successive results are within
> 0.001:

NestUntilList can be used to solve [Project Euler Problem 25](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25). That's why I was interested in the idea of NestUntilList.

The problem is named 1000-digit Fibonacci number, and the question is

> What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to
> contain 1000 digits?

Here is the solution:

```wl
EchoTiming[NestUntil[#+1&,1,IntegerLength[Fibonacci[#]]===1000&]]
```

Output:4782 in 0.045613 s on Wolfram Cloud running Wolfram Language 13.3 in Chrome Browser.